# Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error) server cannot be a server error When I run it in visual

Tags: server, https, django

```
When I run it in visual, it works, but when I deploy it to the server, the part with the url is https://domain/finance/ 


$.ajax({
    url: 'https://example.ca/finance/',
    beforeSend : function(jqXHR, settings) {
               jqXHR.setRequestHeader("x-csrftoken", '{{ csrf_token }}');
                        },
                        data: data,
                        processData: false,
                        method: 'POST',
                        contentType: false,
                        enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
                        success: function ( qayidanData ) {
                            if( qayidanData == "True"){
                            $('.requiredS2, .requiredS1').each(function () {
                                $(this).val('');      
                            });
                            $('#step2').hide();
                            $('#step1').show();
                            Swal.fire('You have successfully registered');
                            
                          }
                        }
    
                    });
    jquery-3.6.0.min.js:2 XHR failed loading: POST "https://example.ca/finance/".
    send    @   jquery-3.6.0.min.js:2
    ajax    @   jquery-3.6.0.min.js:2
    (anonymous) @   (index):433
    dispatch    @   jquery-3.6.0.min.js:2
    v.handle    @   jquery-3.6.0.min.js:


def finance(request):
    
    address_list = Address.objects.all()
    
    context =  {
        'address_list': address_list
    }
    
    if request.method == "POST":
        
        
        first_name = request.POST.get('first_name')
        last_name = request.POST.get('last_name')
        email = request.POST.get('email')
        phone_number = request.POST.get('phone_number')
        employer_name = request.POST.get('employer_name')
        employer_phone_number = request.POST.get('employer_phone_number')
        postal_code = request.POST.get('postal_code')
        street_name = request.POST.get('street_name')
        province = request.POST.get('province')
        city = request.POST.get('city')
        current_occupation = request.POST.get('current_occupation')
        annual_gross_income = request.POST.get('annual_gross_income')
        years_with_current_employer = request.POST.get('years_with_current_employer')
        home_ownership_type = request.POST.get('home_ownership_type')
        mortgage_company_or_landlord = request.POST.get('mortgage_company_or_landlord')
        monthly_rent_or_mortgage_payment = request.POST.get('monthly_rent_or_mortgage_payment')
        preferred_lender = request.POST.get('preferred_lender')
        print(email)
        print(mortgage_company_or_landlord)
        
        data = Finance.objects.create(
            first_name = first_name,
            last_name = last_name,
            email = email,
            phone_number = phone_number,
            employer_name = employer_name,
            employer_phone_number = employer_phone_number,
            postal_code = postal_code,
            street_name = street_name,
            province = province,
            city = city,
            current_occupation = current_occupation,
            annual_gross_income = annual_gross_income,
            years_with_current_employer = years_with_current_employer,
            home_ownership_type = home_ownership_type,
            mortgage_company_or_landlord = mortgage_company_or_landlord,
            monthly_rent_or_mortgage_payment = monthly_rent_or_mortgage_payment,
            preferred_lender = preferred_lender,
        )
        
        if data:
            print(data)
            return render(request,'register2.html')
            
    
    return render(request,'finance.html')
```

everything works fine in visual but the server does not submit

Comment: hi, this is not a great question, first of all this is probably not the correct stack exchange. you can try stackoverflow.com. but for your issue, you should check server logs (python output) to see what's the actual error.

Comment: @Cagri I run the project, I submit the form, it works, but the server does not submit jquery-3.6.0.min.js:2 POST https://domain.ca/finance/ 500 (Internal Server Error)